# Swap the address of two ObjectiveC objects

Tags: objective-c

I have the code to swap the address of two NSString objects,
but the output is completely unexpected.
Can anyone explain why I can't swap the reference of two objects.

```
    NSString* spt1 = @"spt1";
    NSString* spt2 = @"spt2";

    NSLog(@"spt1=%p", &spt1);
    NSLog(@"spt2=%p", &spt2);

    NSString* stmp = spt1;
    spt1 = spt2;
    spt2 = stmp;

    NSLog(@"spt1=%p", &spt1);
    NSLog(@"spt2=%p", &spt2);
```

output:

```
spt1=0x7fff53f5d208
spt2=0x7fff53f5d200
swap: spt1=0x7fff53f5d208
swap: spt2=0x7fff53f5d200
```

Comment: The object references have been swapped successfully, but you aren't printing the references, you're printing the address of the references. Take off the `&`s in NSLog to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

No you did not (cannot) swap the address of objects.

The object always live in heap and cannot be moved. You can move the content, but not the object.

What you have done is swap the *value* of `spt1` and `spt2`. However, the *address* of `spt1` and `spt2` (i.e. `&spt1` and `&spt2`) remains the same.

Try this code instead. You can see the values are swapped but not the addresses.

```
NSLog(@"spt1=%p, &spt1=%p", spt1, &spt1);
NSLog(@"spt2=%p, &spt2=%p", spt2, &spt2);

NSString* stmp = spt1;
spt1 = spt2;
spt2 = stmp;

NSLog(@"spt1=%p, &spt1=%p", spt1, &spt1);
NSLog(@"spt2=%p, &spt2=%p", spt2, &spt2);
```